# How to make the following dta、

Tags: stata

Original data has a string variable "country"

```
country
US
US
UK
US
Canada
UK
US
Canada
```

To reduce file size, I want to turn this into a numeric variable, something like

```
country
1
1
2
1
3
2
1
3
```

while also separately saving a file correspondence.dta that looks like
numeric

```
country
1 US
2 UK
3 Canada
```

Changing it to numeric to reduce the file size could be done by doing this.

```
encode country, gen(country2)
drop country
gen country3=country2
drop country2
rename country3 country
```

But since I am using country3, but not country2 (which has string label), this data now do not contain string information that I need although file size has been successfully reduced.
I need that correspondence.dta file.
How can I generate that while also simultaneously reducing file size like this?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1716952-why-in-panel-data-xtset-stata-doesn-t-recognize-the-monthly-frequencies-of-date It's good practice to tell people about cross-posting elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the value labels with `label save country2 using country_labels.do`. This will create a do-file that can be used to re-create your value label. This is sufficient if you continue working in Stata.

If you really want to store it as a second .dta you can modify the do file as follows. In the do-file editor go on Edit->Find->Replace... then type `label define country2`  into the find field and leave replace empty, then hit replace all. After that, do the same with `, modify`. Then add the following lines above the remaining part of the do file

```
clear
//change str50 to a bigger number if some country names are longer than 50 characters
input ID str50 country
```

And these lines at the end

```
end
save correspondence.dta, replace
```